# How to update MySQL table with result from temp table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named **assp1** with fields *FirstName*, *LastName*, *Maths* and *Overall_Ranking*. I am running a query that will rank each student based on the *Maths* score. The query works fine, but it has temporary variables with a temp table. So it only displays the result of the query but does not affect the table. What I want is to place the result of the query into the *Overall_Ranking* field. So that the rankings in descending order will show who came 1st to last. Below is the code, please show how I can place the result into the *Overall_Ranking* column of the **assp1** table.

```
SELECT assp1.FirstName, assp1.Maths, assp1.LastName, @prev := @curr , @curr := Total_Score, @rank := IF( @prev = @curr , @rank , @rank +1 ) AS Overall_Ranking
FROM assp1, (
SELECT @curr := NULL , @prev := NULL , @rank :=0
)tmp_tbl
WHERE assp1.Grade = 'Grade7' && assp1.class = '7A' && YEAR( assp1.created_at ) = YEAR( CURDATE( ) )
ORDER BY assp1.Total_Score DESC
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you join both original and your SELECT

I simplified your query a bit

```
UPDATE assp1 a INNER JOIN (SELECT assp1.FirstName, assp1.Maths, assp1.LastName, @rank := IF( @curr = Total_Score , @rank , @rank +1 ) AS Overall_Ranking, @curr := Total_Score as Total_Score
FROM assp1, (
SELECT @curr := NULL , @prev := NULL , @rank :=0
)tmp_tbl
WHERE assp1.Grade = 'Grade7' && assp1.class = '7A' && YEAR( assp1.created_at ) = YEAR( CURDATE( ) )
ORDER BY assp1.Total_Score DESC) b ON a.FirstName = b.FirstName AND a.Maths = b.Maths  AND a.LastName = b.LastName 
SET a.Overall_Ranking = b.Overall_Ranking
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly, strongly encourage you to use window fucntions:

```
UPDATE assp1 a JOIN
       (SELECT a.*,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a.Total_Score DESC) as seqnum
        FROM assp1 a
        WHERE a.Grade = 'Grade7' AND A.class = '7A' AND
              YEAR( assp1.created_at ) = YEAR( CURDATE( ) )
       ) a2
       ON a.FirstName = a2.FirstName AND a.LastName = a2.LastName
    SET a.overall_ranking = a2.seqnum;
```

Note that this assumes that student names are unique for identifying each row.

Why do I recommend this?  First, setting variables in non-`SET` statements is deprecated in MySQL, starting with MySQL 8.0.  So, variables are just not the way to go.

Second, if you were to use variables in an earlier version of MySQL, then you have to be very careful:  *MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.* So, you cannot set a variable in one expression and use it in another, safely.

Comment: thank you and I shall consider this approach. Really appreciate that insight.